# How to bring only complete paths via gremlin path?

Tags: titan, gremlin, tinkerpop3

My gremlin query looks like this:

```
g.V.has('someProp','A').as('x').in.loop('x'){it.loops<100}{true}.path()
```

the result:

```
==>[v[768], v[1792]]
==>[v[768], v[1536]]
==>[v[768], v[1792], v[2048]]
==>[v[768], v[1792], v[2048], v[2304]]
```

But I don't want the intermediary paths in the result. I need just two complete paths:
eg.:

```
==>[v[768], v[1536]]
==>[v[768], v[1792], v[2048], v[2304]]
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

Already [answered](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/gremlin-users/cPxZRfGpP2E/MBfDnMFQBAAJ) on the Gremlin users mailing list, but here it is again:

The `{true}` tells the `loop` step to emit all vertices, hence you'll see each and every path. This should work:

```
g.V().has('someProp','A').as('x').in()
   .loop('x') {it.loops<100} {!it.object.inE().hasNext()}.path()
```

Now `loop()` only emits those vertices that don't have an in-edge.